# AutoSizeTextTypeUniform not working on samsung

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-components

I have a simple layout containing some views. This TextView has

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

The autosizing is set programmatically like so..

```
  if (Utils.isOreoOrGreater()) {
                LinkTv.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(1, 14, 1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP)
            }
```

My issue is on a Samsung Galaxy S9, it will not resize the text and keeps using an ellipsis. I've tried this in XML file and programmatically. Has anyone encountered this on a Samsung??

EDIT: Upon further inspection, the TextView is having its `AutoSizeTextType` changed from NONE to UNIFORM but the textsize is not being adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having issues with `autoSizeTextType` on single line text views. Make sure to set `android:maxLines = 1` instead of `android:singleLine = true`, this solved the problem for me. However I'm not sure whats happening under the hood that causes this problem.